# How to get Activity from Flutter Android's PlatformView

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

Is it possible to get the current activity from my native Android code (as shown in FooView.java's constructor, I need to provide an activity)?

I need FooView.java itself to check for camera permissions and to check if ARCore is installed. I'm fairly new to Flutter and it's platform integration and I couldn't find answers online. If it's a Flutter Plugin the activity is accessible thru `registrar.activity()`, but I don't have a registrar since I did the non-Plugin approach (I believe it's called [App registration](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views?tab=android-platform-views-java-tab#on-the-platform-side)).

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    flutterEngine.getPlatformViewsController().getRegistry().registerViewFactory("fooView", new FooViewFactory());
  }
}
```

FooView.java

```
public class FooView implements PlatformView {
  private boolean requestInstall = true;

  FooView(Context context, int id, Map<String, Object> creationParams) {
    Activity someActivity = ?????; // TODO: Find where to get the activity holding the view
    switch (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(someActivity, requestInstall)) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your viewFactory constructor to this to include activity:

```
class NativeViewFactory(val activity: Activity)
```

Now change the native View's constructor which in your case is `FooView`.
Change it to this to include activity.

```
FooView(Activity activity,Context context, int id, Map<String, Object> creationParams)
```

Now the last part is to replace the following code inside your MainActivity:

```
flutterEngine.getPlatformViewsController().getRegistry().registerViewFactory("fooView", new FooViewFactory());
```

with this:

```
flutterEngine.getPlatformViewsController().getRegistry().registerViewFactory("fooView", new FooViewFactory(getActivity()));
```

Comment: Alternately you can get the Activity by taking a View's getContext() and casting it to Activity. The context passed in to the PlatformView constructor, though, isn't an Activity.